# CSS shows when in developer tools but not in file

Tags: php, css

I am currently putting together a website, i have included a dynamic navigation bar developed purely in PHP with my basic ability.

However, using Chrome Dev Tool, i managed to obtain the style i wanted (on current page highlight the page name in white on navigation) , when including the style into my css file, the webpage would not show the style.

```
<?php

function outputHeader ($title){
    echo '<!DOCTYPE html>';
    echo '<html>';
    echo '<head>';
    echo '<title>' . $title . '</title>';
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">';
    echo '</head>';
    echo '<body>';
}

//Output Navigation
echo '<div id="banner">';
echo '<div id="nav">';
echo '<ul>';
function generateNav($pagename){

    $page = array('index.php?' => 'Home', 'playerranking.php?' => 'Player Ranking', 'community.php?' => 'Community', 'register.php?' =>        'Register','login.php' => 'Login',
            );

    foreach ($page as $link => $label){
        if ($pagename == $label){
            echo '<li><a class="current" href="' . $link . '">' . $label . '</li></a>';
        }
        else {
            echo '<li><a href="' . $link . '">' . $label . '</li></a>';
        }

}
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';

} >?
```

The css below

```
    body {

    background: #000;
    margin: 0px; 
}

#banner {
    height: 109px;
    width: 1295px;
    background: #1d1d33;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;

}

#nav {
    margin-right: 10%;
}


#nav ul {
    overflow: visible;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: right;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
    font-family: Calibri, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin-top: 8%;
    float: left;
    padding-right: 30px;
    list-style-type: none;
    overflow: visible;
}

a#current {
    color: #white;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #8f8fa7;
}
```

From what i could see there was no two styles which were over-riding.

Help will be much appreciated

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
a#current {
    color: #white;
}
```

to

```
#nav a.current {
    color: white;
}
```

explanation:
`#` is the selector for `id` attributes, but you want to select the `class` "current". Class names are selected by `.`. Also, when using named colour values, don't prefix them with `#` - you only need the hash for hexadecimal rgb values.

In addition to all that, you have to add `#nav` in front of the rule so that it is more specific than the general rule `#nav a`. (You should also read up on [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in general)

Comment: Thank you very much - I found that the my styling was very general for my specific requirements, your link provided was a great help.